# Syntax highlighting library written in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a free (for commercial use) library for syntax coloring written in c/c++. Are there any out there?

Comment: what platform are you lokking for? for what languages?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you are looking for something to color an existing control or a control with text coloring built in.  If you are looking for the later you could check out Scintilla.

> [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) is a free source code
>   editing component. It comes with
>   complete source code and a license
>   that permits use in any free project
>   or commercial product.

Answer (score 5):

GtkSourceView is a nice library for syntax highlighting and source code editing. It's used in several Gnome editors like gedit and Anjuta and is in active development; it also has a very permissive LGPL license which permits its use in commercial products.

There is also a C++ wrapper called gtksourceviewmm.

http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/

Answer (score 4):

another project to note is the GNU [source-highlite](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/)

Answer (score 2):

found this:

http://colorer.sourceforge.net/