# an objc syntax highlighting library that supports multiple language?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting

I come from the ruby and python worlds where we have many libraries that can syntax highlight arbitrary code from many languages. I am looking for something similar in the objc ecosystem, but i can't seem to find such, is there one available?

The equivalent libraries in Ruby would be [CodeRay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) and [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for Python,

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you include C libraries (ObjC is a superset of C) you have many options

Comment: @sbooth can u link to one? :)) i cant seem to find any..

Comment: I haven't tried most of these, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165449/syntax-highlighting-library-written-in-c-c might help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Banister,

I myself have searched for a long time for a nice and robust Cocoa Syntax Highlighter, and since I'm currently building a code-oriented text editor myself, that would be a major part of the project.

So, I found out that there are plenty of Objective-C/Cocoa -friendly Syntax Highlighting libraries/components. For a starter (for something relatively basic, that is), I would suggest you have a look at :

- [OkudaKit](http://parsekit.com/okudakit/) (using CSS for styling)
- [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm) by Uli Kusterer (pretty nice try)

---

However, if you really need something **POWERFUL, well-tested and still Cocoa-friendly**, I would definitely suggest you to try [**the Scintilla component (for Cocoa)**](https://launchpad.net/scintilla-cocoa). The code is great, and the community (at [Scintilla-Interest](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://groups.google.com/group/scintilla-interest&ei=TpCBT4iPNIPdsgas9aS6AQ&usg=AFQjCNEAUtMk9KokAPyua5vcCKzPY259Yg&sig2=NVJELyhD5njArOQ_eUJe2Q) Group) will gladly help you iron out any issues you may encounter.

**In a few words :**

I'm currently using on an about-to-be-release big project and it's working beautifully for me.

---

### Scintilla

> **Scintilla** is a free library that provides text-editing functions, with
>   an emphasis on advanced features for source code editing. SciTE
>   (cross-platform), Geany, Notepad++ (Windows), and Notepad2 (Windows)
>   are examples of standalone editors based on Scintilla.

**Scintilla Editing Component in use *(SciTe)***

[image: Scintilla Editing Component]

**Features**

> Scintilla supports many features to make code editing easier in
>   addition to **syntax highlighting**. The highlighting method allows the
>   use of **different fonts, colors, styles and background colors**, and is
>   not limited to fixed-width fonts. The control supports error
>   **indicators**, **line numbering** in the margin, as well as **line markers** such
>   as code breakpoints. Other features such as **code folding** and
>   **autocompletion** can be added.

---

- **Download Scintilla** (the Cocoa support has been integrated in the main project) : http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html
- **Example project** (integrating Scintilla with Cocoa) :
  http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mike-lischke/scintilla-cocoa/trunk/files/head:/cocoa/ScintillaTest/
- For **complete documentation**, have a look at : [Scintilla
  Documentation](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html&ei=n5CBT8XbIofZsgbfudXVBA&usg=AFQjCNFrOGa6WnUeYKmwQzJ6U3ZLHHGxEQ&sig2=XIBwiZ2xJN9IO6ktDqOcmg)

Comment: thanks for this, it looks great! however im still a bit of a cocoa neophyte...how exactly do i integrate this into a tiny xcode 4 cocoa app? (also im not sure how to get the code from launchpad as im not familiar with bazaar). Do you have a tiny sample app on github that i can just clone and use ? :P

Comment: @banister OK. As simple as it gets : download the whole project, from the **Download Scintilla** link (in my main answer) and go to the Cocoa/ScintillaTest folder (after you unzip the contents). You'll find a nice Xcode project in there (nothing too complicated; just a ready-made MySQL-highlighting app). Just open it with Xcode and run it. Play with it as you please, and I'm here in case you need anything else. (As for the integration part, you could either create a new project ontop of the Test project, or follow the instructions (at launchpad, I think?))... Good luck! (You'll adore it! ;-))

Comment: great it appears to work, wonderful!! :) One small issue though, the standard readline bindings dont do what they're meant to, ^D, ^E, ^P, etc, aside from that though it's great :) thanks again

Comment: @banister Honestly, I'm not sure what you mean by these bindings (what are ^D, ^E, ^P supposed to do? I'm quite new to Macs... (Oops) and I'm not such a big fun of keyboard shortcuts anyway... apart from the most common that is...). However, in case you really refer to key bindings, there is a command for this (`SCI_ASSIGNCMDKEY` - look in the **Key Bindings** section in the Scintilla Documentation (once you have a good understanding of how scintilla works, you'll simply LOVE this link : http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#KeyBindings)). Don't hesitate to ask me, if you need anything...

Comment: Hi, I've been trying (without success) to get scintilla working in my app. I built the scintilla framework and added it to my app, i renamed my controller to `.mm` and required the scintilla headers in there; but it always dies with "can't find ILexer.h". How did you get scintilla working in your app? any help is appreciated, im going crazy :)

Comment: @banister OK; it took me some time to record and upload the whole thing, but here you are : http://www.screencast.com/t/04BAs5GLKRtn . I think it'll be better than any... long tutorial... ;-)

Comment: wow!! you definitely went beyond the call of duty here, thanks a 1000 times for showing me *exactly* what to do, i never would have figured that out myself!! :) :)

Comment: @banister I **know** what it is NOT to be able to find something you're looking for (especially when it comes to specialized technologies/components/etc), and since you seem to be into... interesting stuff, I bet you'll make good use of it! ;-)

Comment: Hi sorry to bug you again. But i finally tried the instructions in your video, and i did it multiple times to make sure i didnt make a mistake. I get all the errors that you get as you're going through, and gradually reduce the errors by doing the things that you did. However, after i add the preprocessor macros (SCI_LEXER  etc) instead of the program just running fine with no errors i get a missing "ILexer.h" error, here is a screenshot: http://cl.ly/2E111M3c3M2k051n2i11

Comment: What does Scintilla do that extending NSTextView won't do? And isn't Scintilla more trouble in the long run?

Comment: @Cocoaster Well... extending `NSTextView` would obviously be an option - if you're willing to sacrifice some years of your life to create something as complete as Scintilla. Now, if using it may be bothersome in the long run? Sure, as pretty much any piece of source code you're using without having written it yourself. However, just a little study of the documentation is all it takes before you become more than familiar with it. *(Anyway, I suppose it's still a matter of taste. For my needs, Scintilla has been close to perfect.)*

Comment: Thing is, I'm extending NSTextView this right moment and in 5 days I've achieved what Scintilla does, or at least what a cursory look at the documentation says it does.

Answer (score 3):

[Fragaria](https://github.com/mugginsoft/Fragaria) may be useful for future reference.