# C wrapper for pygments

Tags: python, c, pygments

Is it possible to use pygments from a C application? Is there a C library for pygments? I need to use it from a C++ program.

Comment: You cold embed the python interpreter... Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165449

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple to [embed Python](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). Then you can use Pygments from your application.

In particular, look at [section 5.3](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding). There, they use user input for the module and function names, but you could just as easily use a constant `"pygments"` and such to call the necessary functions in the Pygments API.

Comment: There's also [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/).